# ffmpeg - Retrieving video macroblock info with -debug mb_type command

Tags: video, ffmpeg, frame, mpeg, ffprobe

I am trying to get the information about all the **macroblocks** in the frames of a video (mp4).
In particular i'm using the *ffmpeg* command:

```
ffmpeg -debug mb_type -i input.mp4 out.mp4 2> macroblocks.txt
```

It seems to work fine, but... i don't understand **how to parse the output**!

I see that after many uninteresting writings, starts a group of blocks starting with

> "New frame, type: [FRAME TYPE]"

so I assume that these are the blocks referring to each frame containing the type of each macroblock.. but what do the symbols inside mean?

> New frame, type: B [h264 @ 000001c0241c1cc0] d  <  X- <  I  >  >  >  >
>   X  d  d  d  d  d  <  <  d  <  d  >  <  d  d  >  d  <  d  d  d  <  >  <
>   d  <  >  X  <  d  d  >  d  X  d  <  >  d  X  d  >  >  d  d+ d

From the theory I know that there are intra or predicted macroblocks, but i don't understand how to parse this info from the "New frame"-blocks.

- What means i,I,A,<,>,X,|,etc.?

Also often there are sentences like

> nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 2

or

> cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start
>   per stream)

that i really don't understand...
I can't too find a **documentation**..
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best documentation seems to be the source code, currently starting at [line 196 of libavcodec/mpegutils.c](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/918de766f545008cb1ab3d62febe71fa064f8ca7/libavcodec/mpegutils.c#L196).  I won't duplicate everything here, just enough to understand the example line given above.

Each macroblock is described by 3 characters:

1. type and motion vector direction

   - d: `IS_DIRECT && IS_SKIP`
   - <: `!USES_LIST(0)` - Reference to future (List 1, B slices)
   - X: `USES_LIST(0) && USES_LIST(1)` - Reference to past and future (List 1 & 2, B slices)
   - >: `!USES_LIST(1)` - Reference to past (List 0, P or B slices)
   - for more see the code
2. segmentation

   - +: `IS_8X8`
   - -: `IS_16X8`
   - |: `IS_8X16`
   - space: `IS_INTRA || IS_16X16`
   - ?: otherwise
3. interlacing

   - =: `IS_INTERLACED`
   - space: not interlaced

Also interesting in this connection is the [macro block type visualization built into ffmpeg itself](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Debug/MacroblocksAndMotionVectors).

For the NAL unit types see [table 7-1 here](https://yumichan.net/video-processing/video-compression/introduction-to-h264-nal-unit/).

Comment: OK i'll read the code. Another question: do you know why in the report returned by ffmpeg, each frame has different number of "characters" associated (is like they had different number of macroblocks, but i belive it should be not possible)

Comment: @fabridigua Some blocks are subdivided into 8x8 or even 4x4 blocks, so may have more characters based on that, maybe?